# using php 7.1 with nginx server. memcache.dll not working

Tags: memcached, php-7

using PHP7.1 with nginx server. memcache.dll not working
i tried these memcache dlls but no one worked.

```
https://github.com/nono303/PHP7-memcache-dll
```

please help me in this issue.

Comment: what's the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: it do not load extension in phpinfo(). no log error in nginx log.